# Can't insert data to MySQL using PHP

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have been trying to get my form data to database through PHP code but it is not working and I have looked at the code a thousandth times for a possible error but couldn't find one as a beginner. The form will actually submit but nothing gets to the database.

Any fast help would be deeply appreciated. Here is the code:

```
$conn = @mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', 'aboki'); 
if (mysqli_connect_error()) {
die('Connect Error: ' . mysqli_connect_error());
}

$qry = "INSERT INTO users (email, firstName, surname, userName, password, birthday) values ($email, $firstName, $surname, $userName, $password, $userDOB)";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $qry);
```

Comment: If you're going to use mysqli, please use parametrization, which will properly quote and escape all of your variables. You're not quoting the values, which is why it's not inserting.

Comment: Can you show us more code? Need to see where you're getting your values etc. what's `mysqli->query()` returning? Have you tried putting `values` in caps?

Comment: Start by removing the `@` as it suppresses errors.

Comment: Not good to use suppression, like @mysqi... remote the @

Comment: `echo mysqli_error()` usually tells you what is wrong with your query.

Comment: You should be checking the return value of your query like this: `$result = mysqli_query($conn, $qry) or die(mysqli_error($conn));`. This will highlight errors in your query immediately.

Comment: try to output the query before passing it to the mysqli_query function , and take the output and apply it on any mysql client app directly and monitor if the query is right or wrong

Comment: Thanks! Quoting the values solved it!

Comment: Quoting is not enough. They have to be also escaped at the very least.

Comment: @YourCommonSense You don't know that the values need escaping. You don't know that they haven't been sanitised already and are perfectly safe. That part of the code isn't shown.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
$qry = "INSERT INTO users (email, firstName, surname, userName, password, birthday) 
values ('$email', '$firstName', '$surname', '$userName', '$password', '$userDOB')";
```

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, you are not quoting the values which is why it is not inserting...

This will fix it (**But I strongly recommend you do not use this method!)**:

```
$qry = "INSERT INTO users (email, firstName, surname, userName, password, birthday) values ('$email', '$firstName', '$surname', '$userName', '$password', '$userDOB')";
```

### The Correct Method

You would be better off making the most of the predefined functions that `mysqli` offers and binding these parameters in a prepared statement like so:

```
mysqli_prepare($conn,"INSERT INTO users (email, firstName, surname, userName, password, birthday) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");

mysqli_stmt_bind_param($conn, 'TYPES_HERE',$email, $firstName, $surname, $userName, $password, $birthday)
```

Comment: Why don't you use mysqli prepared statements yourself? Are you sure your codes are safe?

Comment: @YourCommonSense I use prepared statements myself! However, I use PDO not MySQLi so my syntax may be incorrect. The code above is merely an example of what the OP should aim towards doing. The first solution was simply to solve the issue, however much you and I would disagree with using such method...

Comment: It's not about "disagreement". It's about working code. Add execute() at least. and line of 's' is better for copy-paste

Comment: @YourCommonSense I agree :-)

Answer (score 0):

I have solution for data Insert , You can try it out.

```
$conn= mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "my_password", "world");
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
exit();
}
$query = "INSERT INTO users 
(email, firstName, surname, userName, password, birthday) VALUES
($email, $firstName, $surname, $userName, $password, $userDOB)";
 mysqli_query($conn, $query);
 printf ("New Record has id %d.\n", mysqli_insert_id($link));
 mysqli_close($link);
```

As you having mysqli in Query the syntax quite different,

Feel free to ask further Question.

Thanks

Answer (score -6):

example:

```
$stmt = mysqli_prepare($conn, "SELECT District FROM City WHERE Name=?")) {
$stmt->bind_param("s", $city);
$stmt->execute();
```

Comment: I bet this answer got so massively downvoted because of its "laziness". If you can't or don't want to write a textual explanation, at least write a code that is related to the query in question, not just abstract example.